# How can I tell what information a website is posting to the server from my browser?

Tags: http, post

I am just asking this out of interest, I did a Google search and all that came up was a lot of information about viruses and stuff.

Basically, I want to be able to see the data that websites are posting to their servers from my browser, if there is any way of doing this.

I am running Chrome but have Firefox, Safari, Opera and IE9 available if there is a solution that exists on those browsers...

Comment: If i understand your question correctly, i guess firebug can help you to see incoming and outgoing request informations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any http debugger (Fiddler, Charles Proxy) to see the traffic at the http level.
You can use any network monitor (Microsoft Network Monitor) to see the traffic at the network level (all network procotols physically going through your network adapters).

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of options here. The easiest thing in Chrome is to right click and choose Inspect Element. That will open a frame at the bottom of the window. Some inspection in here will go a long way although I'm sure some chrome extensions exist.

On that panel, checkout the Network Tab and the Resources Tab.